# Fetch StackOverflow questions and save them to a markdown table

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, markdown

I'm trying to write a script that would (a) fetch StackOverflow questions and (b) update a markdown table with new entries.
With github actions I automated this script to run daily.

Idea borrowed from [simonw](https://github.com/simonw/simonw)

Code:

```
import re
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime


URL = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions"
DATE = datetime.utcnow().date()
ROOT = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()


def get_epochs(date):
    """ Get epoch dates for the start and end of the (current) day. """

    start = datetime(
        year=date.year, month=date.month, day=date.day,
        hour=0, minute=0, second=0
    )
    end = datetime(
        year=date.year, month=date.month, day=date.day,
        hour=23, minute=59, second=59
    )
    return int(start.timestamp()), int(end.timestamp())


def fetch_questions(start, end, tag, site="stackoverflow"):
    """ Fetch questions from stackoverflowAPI. """

    _params = {
        "fromdate": start,
        "todate": end,
        "order": "desc",
        "sort": "votes",
        "tagged": tag,
        "site": site,
    }
    return requests.get(URL, params=_params).json()


def build_table(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Build a markdown table from a list of entries. """

    columns = [
        "\n".join(
            "* [{title}]({url}) - {score} votes".format(
                # to prevent code from breaking if special characters are present
                title=re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', item["title"]),
                url=item["link"],
                score=item["score"]
            )
            for item in chunk["items"][:8]
        )
        for chunk in args
    ]
    return columns


def replace_chunk(content, marker, chunk, inline=False):
    """ Replace chunks of README.md """

    r = re.compile(
        r"<!\-\- {} starts \-\->.*<!\-\- {} ends \-\->".format(marker, marker),
        re.DOTALL,
    )
    if not inline:
        chunk = "\n{}\n".format(chunk)
    chunk = "<!-- {} starts -->{}<!-- {} ends -->".format(marker, chunk, marker)
    return r.sub(chunk, content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    readme = ROOT / "README.md"
    start, end = get_epochs(DATE)

    pandas, beautifulsoup, code_review = build_table(
        fetch_questions(start, end, tag="pandas"),
        fetch_questions(start, end, tag="beautifulsoup"),
        fetch_questions(start, end, tag="python", site="codereview")
    )

    readme_contents = readme.open().read()
    rewritten = replace_chunk(readme_contents, "date", DATE.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), inline=True)
    rewritten = replace_chunk(rewritten, "pandas", pandas)
    rewritten = replace_chunk(rewritten, "bs", beautifulsoup)
    rewritten = replace_chunk(rewritten, "code_review", code_review)

    with open(readme, "w") as output:
        output.write(rewritten)
```

Markdown file:

```
# Stackoverflow daily top questions: <!-- date starts --> date <!-- date ends -->

<table><tr><td valign="top" width="33%">

### Pandas
<!-- pandas starts -->
pandas content
<!-- pandas ends -->
</td><td valign="top" width="34%">


### BeautifulSoup
<!-- bs starts -->
bs4 content
<!-- bs ends -->
</td><td valign="top" width="34%">


### Python code review submissions
<!-- code_review starts -->
code review content
<!-- code_review ends -->
</td><td valign="top" width="34%">
```

---

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: oh, and how it all works with a github workflows is [here](https://github.com/hp0404/hp0404)

Comment: If this is python 3+, you can tag as [tag:python-3.x]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things look good and well organised at first glance. However, there are a few things you can make use of.

1. Use f-string over using str.format. The former [is more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123579/1190388).
2. You can group the columns and iterate over them, instead of having multiple lines for each section. This way, you can add/remove to this iterable without having to change much of the code itself.
3. When using raw strings, you do not need to escape the `-` character, unless they are being used inside a character set (for regex).
4. The `build_table` can be split to another separate function.
5. Use [type hinting](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/typing).
6. If you're not using `kwargs`, no need to declare them.

---

Rewritten snippets (you might need to fit them in your code accordingly):

```
sections = (
    {'tag': "pandas", "marker": "pandas"},
    {'tag': "beautifulsoup", "marker": "bs"},
    {'tag': "python", "site": "codereview", "marker": "code_review"},
)
for section in sections:
    questions_list = fetch_questions(start, end, **section)
    # Using `**section` might throw an error for the unknown kwarg: `marker`.
    # But it is trivial to handle that.
    .
    ...
```

---

```
def replace_chunk(content: str, marker: str, chunk: str, inline: bool = False):
    """ Replace chunks of README.md """
    r = re.compile(
        rf"<!-- {marker} starts -->.*<!-- {marker} ends -->",
        re.DOTALL,
    )
    if not inline:
        chunk = "\n{}\n".format(chunk)
    chunk = f"<!-- {marker} starts -->{chunk}<!-- {marker} ends -->"
    return r.sub(chunk, content)
```

---

```
def get_item_string(item):
    # to prevent code from breaking if special characters are present
    title = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', item["title"])
    return f"* [{title}]({item['link']}) - {item['score']} votes"

def build_table(*args):
    """ Build a markdown table from a list of entries. """
    columns = [
        "\n".join(
            map(get_item_string, chunk["items"][:8])
        )
        for chunk in args
    ]
    return columns
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks really good, so I'll ask some questions on the design decisions that have been made.

```
Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
```

I haven't used this before, so I may be wrong, but this looks a little fragile.

The Python docs for [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) include a very useful note under parent

[image]

Namely, it may do something unexpected if the path is not an absolute path. From this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116925/3503611), the result returned from `__file__` may be relative, if the directory is in sys.path. In conclusion, you probably want to resolve before getting the parent, to avoid some unexpected paths.

```
ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
```

Also, why set the root based on the file location, rather than `__main__` or a fixed location? Another consideration is `__file__` is not always set, do you care about the use-case of running the code in an interpreter?

---

```
def get_epochs(date):
    """ Get epoch dates for the start and end of the (current) day. """
    ...
```

This code all looks good. I would maybe include a note specifying that the API is inclusive of the end time, and is quantised in seconds. A change to either of these assumptions (which is unlikely) would warrant changing the code here.

---

```
def fetch_questions(start, end, tag, site="stackoverflow"):
    """ Fetch questions from stackoverflowAPI. """

    _params = {
        ...
    }
    requests.get(URL, params=_params).json()
```

Some very minor points

- The API is for stack exchange, not stack overflow.
- You don't need the underscore in front of params. It is a local name to the function, so it doesn't need to be marked private. Keyword args can share their name with the parameter name. `params=params` works.
- I would split up the request, and extracting result as a certain file format. If this function starts returning bad results, it will be easier to debug if the fetch and parsing of results are separated.
- I would change the parameter `tag` to `tags` since you can pass more than one tag by delimiting with ';'. A note on how to use tag would be a good addition to the docstring.

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    readme = ROOT / "README.md"
    start, end = get_epochs(DATE)

    pandas, beautifulsoup, code_review = build_table(
        fetch_questions(start, end, tag="pandas"),
        fetch_questions(start, end, tag="beautifulsoup"),
        fetch_questions(start, end, tag="python", site="codereview")
    )
    
    readme_contents = readme.open().read()
    rewritten = replace_chunk(readme_contents, "date", DATE.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), inline=True)
    rewritten = replace_chunk(rewritten, "pandas", pandas)
    rewritten = replace_chunk(rewritten, "bs", beautifulsoup)
    rewritten = replace_chunk(rewritten, "code_review", code_review)
    
    with open(readme, "w") as output:
        output.write(rewritten)
```

I would move this code to a function, since it will be a little easier to test (and therefore update if needed). What happens if you make a typo in a tag between `fetch_questions` and `replace_chunk`?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Those are very relevant questions. I'll reconsider everything once I have more free time.